# Can not convert I420 to RGB in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

this command work fine:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v --gst-debug-level=2 udpsrc port=1234 ! decodebin ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! autovideosink`

this command not work:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v --gst-debug-level=2 udpsrc port=1234 ! decodebin ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! autovideosink`

error:
`failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named decodebin0 to some pad of GstVideoConvert named videoconvert0`

what is wrong?

importance log:

> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_mpeg4:avdec_mpeg4-0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)10/1

all log:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
>   Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
>   New clock: GstSystemClock
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:src_0: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpeg4VParse:mpeg4vparse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstMultiQueuePad:sink_0: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_mpeg4:avdec_mpeg4-0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpeg4VParse:mpeg4vparse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpeg4VParse:mpeg4vparse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)simple, level=(string)1, codec_data=(buffer)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800553c04871443, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_mpeg4:avdec_mpeg4-0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)simple, level=(string)1, codec_data=(buffer)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d8800553c04871443, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_mpeg4:avdec_mpeg4-0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)10/1
>   /GstCapsFilter:capsfilter2: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420
>   0:00:01.480704357  3721 0x7f3f9809a230 WARN                 default grammar.y:510:gst_parse_no_more_pads: warning: Delayed linking failed.
>   0:00:01.480728456  3721 0x7f3f9809a230 WARN                 default grammar.y:510:gst_parse_no_more_pads: warning: failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named decodebin0 to some pad of GstVideoConvert named videoconvert0
>   WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0: Delayed linking failed.
>   Additional debug info:
>   ./grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
>   failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named decodebin0 to some pad of GstVideoConvert named videoconvert0
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad3: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)10/1
>   Redistribute latency...
>   0:00:01.564689538  3721 0x5644dfac2f70 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop: error: Internal data stream error.
>   0:00:01.564741097  3721 0x5644dfac2f70 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop: error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
>   ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
>   Additional debug info:
>   gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
>   streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
>   Execution ended after 0:00:01.516699193
>   Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   Setting pipeline to READY ...
>   Setting pipeline to NULL ...
>   Freeing pipeline ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely it is due to the fact that the render device that is being chosen does not support RGB as an output format.